# Symfony 5.1 - An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The controller for URI "/_fragment" is not callable")

Tags: php, symfony, twig

recently I update my symfony project (4.1) to 5.1, but my code throws an error when I try embed the controller in twig template:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The controller for URI "/_fragment" is not callable: Controller "SamAngularBundle:System:connectionInfo" does neither exist as service nor as class.").**

But when I run the URL works fine:
[View screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6Tds.png)

Controller code:

```
class SystemController extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController  {
   /**
    * @Route("/angular/connection/info", name="url_angular_connection_info")
    */
   public function connectionInfoAction() {
       return $this->render("@SamAngular/System/connection_info.html.twig");
   }
}
```

Template code:

```
{# empty Twig template #}
<div class="template-foot">    
    {{render(controller('SamAngularBundle:System:connectionInfo'))}}
</div>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bundle:controller:action` syntax was [deprecated in 4.1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26085) and removed in 5.0. It's been replaced by the [`controller::action` syntax](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/templating/embedding_controllers.html).

The same syntax for templates was also [dropped much earlier](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11051) (referenced for completeness, you are already using the new template syntax).

Comment: Great! works for me! I Change to 
 {{render(controller('App\\Sam\\AngularBundle\\Controller\\SystemController::connectionInfoAction'))}} and it works fine, thanks!